# Periodic filesystem replication wih snapshot

Tags: synchronization, replication

I'm looking for a non-realtime replication solution that supports periodic snapshot.

Here's my current situation:

- I have 2 email servers running **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**
- The mail server program I use is Axigen v8.1.1, serving 2000+ mailboxes, with a rate of approx. 2000 emails per hour during workhours
- The configuration is **Master/Slave**, using heartbeat/pacemaker
- Axigen uses its own proprietary database to store all settings and messages
- Most users access the email server using POP3, but some use IMAP4

What I want to implement:

- Every *N* minutes, there should be a snapshot done on the master to be shipped to Slave
- Slave should be able to efficiently store at least *M* latest snapshots, plus 2 daily snapshots, just in case we need to roll back
- (We can live with N minutes of lost emails; all emails are stored in a MailArchiva storage system)

**My original plan** was to implement Axigen's datastore on a ZFS-on-Linux (ZoL) filesystem, with regular snapshots that would be shipped (incrementally) to Slave. However, I was bitten with ZoL's instability during heavy I/O, where I had experienced several incidents of *CPU Soft Lockup*. The ZoL discussion group suggested I reduce the size of the ARC cache, but of course that would impact performance, so I instead revert to an ext4-backed storage on Master. (Might still implement ZFS on Slave, though).

**I'm considering several options:**

1. Reconfigure the Master so that the datastore is on an LVM-backed storage, and regularly create an LVM snapshot to sync to the Slave using `csync2` or `rsnapshot` (and delete the LVM snapshot after a successful sync). On the Slave side, after every successful sync, do a ZFS snapshot to maintain the required number of snapshots & daily snapshots.
2. Implement DRBD in a Master/Slave configuration, with a hard disk-backed storage on Master, but a ZVOL-backed storage on Slave.
3. Implement a Clustered File System that supports snapshots... but which one?

Your thoughts and inputs are very much appreciated.

---

*Edit:* due to my department's budget situation, I can't use a commercial solution. Maybe next year, but unfortunately my need is current.

---

*Edit 2:* the ZoL instability might not be the instability of ZoL itself per se, but I suspect more because of the unbelievable memory churn of the email server (due to some reasons, I have to implement Perdition in front of the Axigen server, and Perdition creates one process per connection, so the server's memory might be severely fragmented and blocks ZoL from claiming some SLABs to grow its ARC Cache)

Comment: maybe look into btrfs?

Comment: @strugee I'm even more hesitant to use btrfs ... no one ever claimed it's ready for production-servers use, while ZFS has had time to mature (in the Solaris universe), and several people has claimed it's ready for production (although there are edge cases like mine).

Comment: true, although apparently the btrfs guys think it's fairly stable. at least, the disk format is. https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2013/04/the-btrfs-backup-experiment/ suggested to experiment with btrfs as the backup filesystem (which, in my situation, would be the Slave server), and wait until it's more stable. So, that still leaves me the problem of what I should deploy on the Master server :-/

Comment: friendly reminder that you can convert ext4 in-place to btrfs and roll it back later if you don't like it

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the ZFS related CPU soft lockup. This https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/ZFS#ARC is related I think.

Answer (score 2):

Well, at least you can consider using [lvmsync](https://github.com/mpalmer/lvmsync) which is «… able to read the metadata that device-mapper uses to keep track of what parts of the block device have changed, and use that information to only send those modified blocks over the network. …»